# Set Authorization Header in WordPress?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, rest, api

i have two WordPress installations and i add a new api route to create new items via api request.

In my first installation everything works, on my second one not.

The only difference is, that i install on the second one the plugin "members".

in both i send the ajax request like the code above:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://website.test/wp-json/wp/v2/posts",
    method: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify( obj ),
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json",
    beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8' );
      xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', 'Basic ' + window.btoa("admin:admin") );
    },
    success: function( data ) {
      console.log( 'success' );
      console.log( data );
    },
    error: function( error ) {
      console.log( 'error' );
      console.log( error );
    }
  });
```

On my second one, which not work i get the unauthorization 401 message but the password is correct and when i try postman everything, for both installations will work.

Comment: Are you sure your Auth is Basic ? It can be Auth2 or something else.

Comment: Yes i'm sure because the Auth Basic works via Postman. When i try the code above it doesn't work.